# How to insert data into temp table using Case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert the data into temp table using `Case` statement below is my code, and with this I am getting this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I'm not able to figure out what I am doing wrong. Is this the correct way of inserting the data into a temp table based on certain condition provided in `Case` statement?

```
DECLARE @temp_idCol TABLE 
                    (
                         uid int IDENTITY(1, 1),
                         id nvarchar(20)
                    )
  
DECLARE @_ThresholdOperator nvarchar(20) = '=', 
        @_Threshold_Val nvarchar(20) = '0.4' 

INSERT INTO @temp_idCol (id) 
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN @_ThresholdOperator = '=' 
                THEN (SELECT q.id 
                      FROM [dbo].[Summit_Twitter_HashtagDetails] q  
                      WHERE q.Ticket_ID IS NULL
                        AND q.SentimentAnalyis_Score = @_Threshold_Val   
                         OR q.IsProcessedOrNot = 0)
            WHEN @_ThresholdOperator = '>' 
                THEN (SELECT q.id 
                      FROM [dbo].[Summit_Twitter_HashtagDetails] q  
                      WHERE q.Ticket_ID IS NULL
                        AND q.SentimentAnalyis_Score > @_Threshold_Val   
                         OR q.IsProcessedOrNot = 0)
            WHEN @_ThresholdOperator = '<' 
                THEN (SELECT q.id 
                      FROM [dbo].[Summit_Twitter_HashtagDetails] q  
                      WHERE q.Ticket_ID IS NULL
                        AND q.SentimentAnalyis_Score < @_Threshold_Val    
                         OR q.IsProcessedOrNot = 0)  
        END AS id 
    FROM
        [dbo].[Summit_Twitter_HashtagDetails]
```

Comment: case is an expression returning a scalar value not a control flow statement

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression can only return 1 value.

But you can use `IF` and `ELSE`

**Simplified example:**

> ```
> create table test (id int identity primary key, col decimal(9,1));
> insert into test (col) values (0.1),(0.2),(0.3),(0.4),(0.5);
> ```

> ```
> declare @ids table (id int);
> declare @_ThresholdOperator varchar(2) = '>', 
>         @_Threshold_Val nvarchar(20) = '0.3';
>
> IF @_ThresholdOperator = '='
>   insert into @ids (id) 
>   select id from test where col = @_Threshold_Val;
> ELSE IF @_ThresholdOperator = '<'
>   insert into @ids (id) 
>   select id from test where col < @_Threshold_Val;
> ELSE IF @_ThresholdOperator = '>'
>   insert into @ids (id) 
>   select id from test where col > @_Threshold_Val;
> ELSE BEGIN 
>      insert into @ids (id) values (0);
>      update @ids set id = id + 42;
>      END;
>
> select * from @ids;
> ```

| id |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=089d67915cb2fecdc133446a863eae90)*

**Extra**

A `CASE` could still be used in the `WHERE` clause.
As long it only returns 1 value.
It's just not sargable.

```
  insert into @ids (id) 
  select id from test 
  where case @_ThresholdOperator 
        when '=' then iif(col=@_Threshold_Val,1,0)
        when '<' then iif(col<@_Threshold_Val,1,0)
        when '>' then iif(col>@_Threshold_Val,1,0)
        end = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms , I have also tried with If else , and it is working fine.

Comment: That's good. Guess this doesn't really need [Dynamic Sql](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) then.

Comment: Thanks for the solution you provided for Case statement i have modified it according to my need and its working perfectly.